# How to solve these kind of problems in Probability?

Tags: probability

Your company owns a data center of n>1,000 computers. You learned that some of these computers may be infected by a virus. Due to the security setup, this infection will not affect your data center if less than 10% of the computers got infected.
Since checking for an infection is expensive, your boss wants to perform the check only on a (uniformly random) sample of 10 computers. Your boss claims that if at least 10% of the computers got infected, then with probability at least 9/10, at least one of the sampled computers is infected.
Prove or refute your boss’ claim. You need to show a convincing argument in either case, e.g. give a calculation and/or a counter example.

What I did - 
If 10% of the computers are infected, non-infected - 90%
The probability that all 10 computers in consideration are infected - 0.9^10
Probability that at least 1 computer is defective out of those 10 - 1-0.9^10 and that comes around 0.65. But the boss said it to be 0.9. Hence proved wrong.

Not sure if I am calculating the right thing here though. Getting confused with at least 10% of computers getting infected part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the event that none of the 10 sample computers is infected. Then 
$$
P(E)=\frac{\dbinom{N}{10}}{\dbinom{n}{10}}
$$
where $N$ is the number of non-infected computers in the entire population. Note that $P(E)$ is a function of $n$ and $N$. For all $N\leq 0.9 n$ and $n>1000$, the boss claims that
$$
P(E)\leq 0.1.
$$
Put $n=2000$ and $N=17000$ to see that the Boss's claim is false as in this case
$$
P(E)>0.1.
$$

Comment: Did you mean $n=20,000$ at the end?